# Terraform custom provider access to schema

Tags: go, terraform

Is it possible to access the schema of my custom Terraform provider at runtime, e.g. from the Create method?

I see that the lib has an [addrToSchema](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/blob/main/helper/schema/field_reader.go#L47) function, but it's internal.

In particular, I would like to know if an attribute is `Sensitive`.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you are trying to achieve here. It is currently unclear what you are asking i.e. which schema object in the provider, which kind of access, etc.

Comment: @MattSchuchard In particular, I would like to know if an attribute is `Sensitive`.

Comment: You could pass an assigned variable (likely Struct) to the resource schema argument, and then you could access the `Sensitive` attribute from that. The AzureRM provider follows this design for some resources.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thank you, so I guess that I should do that. We have some existing resources and I wanted to make minimal changes. But I will need to refactor the schemas like you suggest.

Comment: Yeah you can kind of see an Azure example for this at https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-azurerm/blob/v3.0.2/internal/services/appservice/windows_web_app_resource.go#L135-L141.